# Pyperplan with action costs support or alternative wanted

Tags: planning, pddl

I'm using pyperplan in my project, however I'm very limited in choice of planning domains, as pyperplan does not support PDDL v2

Do you know of any pyperplan fork, that has this functionality? Basic +1 action costs should be enough, they are my only problem right now.

Eventually, do you know of any pyperplan-ish alternative that would support more modern versions of PDDL?

I'm planning to implement the functionality on my own, I ran through the code, and it shouldn't be THAT hard, it looks pretty set up for that.

I went through all forks listed on github, but none of them has this feature. I've also tried looking up such clone myself, or looking up any related articles, but nothing of value showed up.

I will be really grateful for any tips!

Comment: What is it exactly you need from pyperplan? If it's just ease of use planning, then you can check out the planutils project. Many planners of many formalisms there.

Comment: @BohdanKopčák if I understand you well you are looking for a [PDDL planner](https://planning.wiki/ref/planners) which supports `action costs`, if that was the case I recommend you use the [fast-downward](https://github.com/aibasel/downward) planner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.